# Wordpress Rewrite Rule works with numeric param but not alphanumeric

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to parse parameters from a URL via .htaccess and url rewriting in wordpress.

Problem - it works if the query param is numeric but not if it's alphanumeric

1. As expected mysite.com/members/12345 will map to to mysite.com/members?membername=123 where i can view the query var parameter.
2. For some reason, mysite.com/members/abc will 404.

.htaccess settings:

```
RewriteRule ^members/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?page_id=1107&membername=$1
RewriteRule ^members/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?page_id=1107&membername=$1
```

[page_id 1107= ] /members page.
I have the following set in functions.php so that I don't lose the query parameter

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');

function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'membername';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
```

I have no idea why it works with numbers, but not with any alpha characters. Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: my permalinks structure is /%category%/%postname%
When i remove this permalink structure (reverting to mysite.com/?p=123), the rewrite works as expected - so I guess the category rewrite rule is messing things up here.. how to override for /members/ only??

Comment: I think it's not about .htaccess, your .htaccess is correct. Dose the link www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?page_id=1107&membername=abc works?  I thinks it's 404.

Comment: yep that works fine and loads the appropriate page.